# I have assigned a variable from my r shiny file to the global environment but my script file cannot access it

Tags: r, shiny

My aim is to upload a dataset within my application(R shiny app) and perform computations on this dataset using my external R script. Given that both my application and script are in the same directory, I have tried to change the scope of the variable containing the script path and put into the global environment so that it is accessible by both files. But when I run my script file, at first it has to read the file but however, it says that the variable has not been found, even if it is found inside the global environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to add that I am new to the R language and if ever there are better ways of doing it, please consider commenting. Thank you in advance.

My code segment is here:

```
#Inside the Application's code
observeEvent(req(input$datasetRNACount),{

tryCatch({

  infileDatasetRNACount <-input$datasetRNACount

  if(is.null(infileDatasetRNACount)){return()}

  else{

    file.copy(infileDatasetRNACount$datapath,file.path(getwd(), infileDatasetRNACount$name),overwrite = TRUE)
   # put the variable in the global environment
    rawCountFile<<- input$datasetRNACount$datapath
  }

},

# The script code
dataseq <- read.delim(rawCountFile)
```

[The object "rawCountFile" was not found as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zVnD.png)
[While the variable is present inside the global environment as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKToy.png)

Comment: Have you tried using ````source("script.R")```` in your app script?

Comment: A button in the application triggers the script via source("script.R"). It runs the code and gives the error.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what causes the error without your full code

Comment: I would gladly send you the files if you wish. I've been trying since last 2 weeks and have not got any improvements. Can I private message you?